# Euler Lagrange Equation/ Magnetic Hamiltonian

Tags: differential-geometry

I don't know how to solve the following equations in local coordinates: On a manifold Q with Riemannian metric, define 
$L(x,v) = \frac{1}{2}g_x(v,v)+\theta_x(v)-V(x)$.

My problem is: given a coordinate charts on $TQ, \{x_i, v_i\}$. I can write $\theta = \theta ^idx_i, v = v_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $. Then $\theta(v) = \theta^i v_i $. When taking partial derivative, is $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v_i}(x, v) = \theta^i?$

Comment: I think so too: in a local chart, you have 
$
L(x,v) = \frac12 g^{ij}(x) v_i v_j + \theta^i(x) v_i - V(x).
$
So  
$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_i} = g^{ij}v_j + \theta^i(x),
$ 
and 
 $
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^i} = \partial_i g^{jk}(x)v_j v_k + \partial_i \theta^j(x) v_j - \partial_i V(x).
$

Comment: Thanks! We get the same result.